# Submitting an array with a key via JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat, servlets

im submitting an array of values via jquery ajax, but my servlet only picks up the first value in the array, when it has many more elements.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myServlet",
      data: ({'item':itemsArr})     
});
```

the array looks something like: `var lovelyArray = ["cake", "thong", "supermanDoll"];`

comes out the other side like: `&item=cake` .. and thats it.

i'm expecting it to come out like `item=cake&item=thong&item=supermanDoll`

Any help is much appreciated on this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to serialize your array, like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myServlet",
      data: $.param({'item': itemsArr})  // item[]=cake&item[]=thong&item[]=supermanDoll
});
```

The above output assumes that you are using jQuery 1.4+. If you are using jQuery 1.3.2 or earlier, the output will look like:

```
item=cake&item=thong&item=supermanDoll
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude. anyway to achieve the same output with 1.3.2 with 1.4+ i.e item=cake&item=thong&item=supermanDoll

Answer (score 0):

You want this syntax instead taken from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
```