# jQuery $.ajax method only sends one item from my serialized array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, tomcat, post

My tomcat log is only showing one item being passed in..

```
var itemArr = ["someItem", "someItem2", "someItem3"];

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myServlet",
     data: $.param({item: itemArr})    
  });
```

The array contains around 20 elements.

Also if i do:

```
var params = $.param({item: itemArr});
alert(params);
```

All the values come out formatted as `item=someitem&item=someitem2`..etc etc
But the ajax post only outputs the first item from the array. I want them all passed through to the server in the request.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Using version 1.3.2 also tried with 1.4.4 - same problem

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: That is because (I think) on the server side, any subsequent 'items' overwrite the previous 'item'. You seem to be using jQuery 1.3.2 or less. This could be one of the reasons why the jQuery guys decided to change how `$.param` works. I suggest you upgrade. Also, what server language are you using?

Comment: @karim79: I don't think the items overwriting previous items is an issue, it should be interpreted as an array.

Comment: @davidbuttar - I want to think that, but the OP says that only one value is getting captured on the server (as per my understanding).

Comment: @karim79: The item displayed in tomcat is the first item in the array, its almost as if the '&' is stopping further items being displayed. As for the server side language - Java.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `$.param()` call should just be this:

```
var itemArr = ["someItem", "someItem2", "someItem3"];

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myServlet",
     data: $.param(itemArr)    
});
```

EDIT: Nick is onto something there...

From the `jQuery.param()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
// <=1.3.2: 
$.param({ a: [2,3,4] }) // "a=2&a=3&a=4"
// >=1.4:
$.param({ a: [2,3,4] }) // "a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4"
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

Maybe something like this will work for you, to emulate the 1.4 behavior:

```
var itemArr = ["someItem", "someItem2", "someItem3"];
var paramed = decodeURIComponent($.param({ 'item[]': itemArr }));
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/EHd78/1/

Comment: this is a follow-up to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401659/submitting-an-array-with-a-key-via-jquery-ajax/

Comment: +1 - Nice edit. Still, @Uncle - you must consider upgrading :)

Comment: Ok so i tried your last edit(decodeURIComponent) no change still the same problem. Tried with 1.4.4 as well and still the same problem. So confused why its only sending the first item. COuld it be something to do with tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Oh right I missed the first sentence, yes you will only get one item passed to your server it should be an array.

This from firebug when I make that request,

```
item[]  someItem
item[]  someItem2
item[]  someItem3
```